# get only selected column from database table laravel 5 eloqouent

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to get only the selected column in my database using Laravel 5 Eloquent, here's what i tried

```
$selected_vote = users_details::all()->get('selected_vote');
```

but unfortunately and sadly, not working. Any ideas, help, clues, suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't call `all`. Pass an array of columns to the `get` method:

```php
$selected_votes = users_details::get(['selected_vote']);
```

If you just want a simple list for that column, you can use the `lists` method:

```php
$selected_votes = users_details::lists('selected_vote');
```

If you only want a single value from the first row, use this:

```php
$selected_vote = users_details::value('selected_vote');
```

Answer (score 1):

You should pass an array of values to the get() method, like so:

```
users_details::get(['selected_vote']);
```

or you can use lists() method:

```
users_details::lists('selected_vote');
```